how to handle await Task return null case in c#
I met one issue when handling await Task return null case.
In below code, if GetByName() method return null. Then in my invoke code GUI will get exception below. I think it is because the GetByName() return null and I invoke it use await.
May I know is there any better way to handle such case? My purpose is just do something when return is not null, and do other thing if return is null. Both make sense for the logic.
blazor.webview.js:1  One or more errors occurred
(Status(StatusCode="Cancelled", Detail="No message returned from method."))
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at DataView2.Pages.Dataset.ImportDataset.PickFileFath()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at MudBlazor.MudBaseButton.OnClickHandler(MouseEventArgs ev)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)

public async Task<DatabaseRegistry> GetByName(string datasetName) 
{
    try
    {
        var entities = await _repository.GetAllAsync();
        var returnValue = entities.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == datasetName);
        if (returnValue == null)
            return await Task.FromResult<DatabaseRegistry>(null);  // here I mean return null
        else
            return returnValue;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the exception
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");

        // Optionally, throw a gRPC-specific error to return a meaningful message
        throw new RpcException(new Status(StatusCode.Internal, "An error occurred while retrieving the database."));
    }
}

// Below is the code to invoke GetByName method
var curDbService = await appEngine.DatabaseRegistryService.GetByName(result.FileName);
if (curDbService != null)
{
    // Do something here
}
else
{
    // Do others
}


You are getting all the entities from the DB and then using just one. This is massively inefficient. Rather do var retVal = await _repository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(filter) (if your repository implementation doesn't support extensions it needs revision).

If your goal is to return null value, you should just mark your method value as nullable:  Task<DatabaseRegistry?> and then just: return null;

@Richard yes, this is inefficient, better to use filter

@ZecosMAX will still get the same exception, even though change to return null and Task<DatabaseRegistry?>

The underlying cause here is your UI needs to handle null: there is no sign the quoted code is in the call stack when the exception is thrown.

@Richard I do could use try/catch to catch the null exception in UI code. but seems it is not a good way. because null case should be a normal case. my understanding is it should be handled in try block.

If you have marked method as async you don't need to use Task.FromResult and await it additionally. You can simply write return null;
Task.FromResult is used to return already completed task with the result set. It is used when you have method and it is not marked async and you want to return result that does not need to be awaited. Example
public Task<int> Method()
{
    return Task.FromResult(1);
}

Such implementation does not make much sense, but it is useful, for example, when you have to implement async method from interface, but your implementation is fully sync.
In you scenario you have already async method and you can return results directoly, without wrapping them in Task.

but in my above code, even though I change the 'return await Task.FromResult(null); ' to 'return null'. it will still get the same exception in GUI
